# Android How to prevent calling handler.postDelayed multiple times?

Tags: android, android-handler

I have create a method that after 5 seconds, set ImageView's alpha to 0.4 using handler.postDelayed.
The problem is that the method is called multiple times because of it is located inside of Touch-listener's `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. So I am looking for a method that detect if the handler.postDelayed is active.

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

private init(){
     runnable = new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
             ImageView.setAlpha(0.4f);
         }
     }
 }

 private void setAlpha(){
     handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(runnable,5000);
 }

 private void cancleHandler(){
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Keep a reference to the Handler instead of a creating a brand new one each time.

2: [Check if the runnable is already posted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#hasCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) and don't post a new one if it is.

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

private init(){
     handler = new Handler();
     runnable = new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
             ImageView.setAlpha(0.4f);
         }
     }
 }

 private void setAlpha(){
     if (!handler.hasCallbacks(runnable)) {
         handler.postDelayed(runnable,5000);
     }
 }

 private void cancleHandler(){
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
 }
```

Comment: `hasCallbacks` was added in API level 29

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the problem was using different instance for handler. it's interesting approach that using the hasCallbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing the callback before adding another one, and using the same handler instance:

```
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    
    private init(){
         handler = new Handler();
         runnable = new Runnable(){
             @Override
             public void run(){
                 ImageView.setAlpha(0.4f);
             }
         }
     }
    
     private void setAlpha(){
         handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
         handler.postDelayed(runnable,5000);
     }
    
     private void cancleHandler(){
         handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was using different instance of handler in this case.